# Scramble an nx1 matrix in matlab efficiently?

Tags: matlab

I need to randomly scramble the values of an nx1 matrix in matlab. I'm not sure how to do this efficiently, I need to do it many times for n > 40,000.

Example

Matrix before:

1 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1

Scrambled:

3 5 2 1 2 2 3 4 1 4 5 2

thank you

Comment: This depends on a few things, the biggest one being how 'scrambled' this matrix has to be. Is it sufficient to swap just some values or should all be moved around?

Comment: randomly scrambled entirely is the intention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data is stored in matrix `data`, then you can generate "scrambled" data using [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) like so:

```
scrambled = data(randperm(numel(data)));
```

This is sampling *without* replacement, so every value in `data` will appear once in `scrambled`.

For sampling *with* replacement (values in `data` may appear in `scrambled` multiple times and some may not appear at all), you could use `randi` like this:

```
scrambled = data(randi(numel(data),1,numel(data)));
```